# Serialization error in C

Tags: c

I've an array of the following struct

```
typedef struct PATH{
    int server1;
    int server2;
    int weight;
}PATH;
```

I'm serializing it into the string using the following function.

```
char* serialize(PATH** arr, int sz){

    char* buffer = calloc(50, sizeof(int));

    char* str = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < sz ; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(str, "%d %d %d\n", arr[i]->server1, arr[i]->server2, arr[i]->weight);
        strcat(buffer, str);

    }

    return buffer;
}
```

And then trying to print it in main using the following two lines of code.

```
char* msg = serialize(paths, vector->numEdges);
 printf("%s\n", msg);
```

I end up with a segmentation fault.

Comment: a few problems with the code: 1) the `str` pointer is never set to point to any specific memory, so any reference to where `str` points is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  2) the call to `sprintf()` does not place a NUL string termination byte into the end of the used part of the array, so `strcat()` does not know where to stop copying characters. which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: why the double pointer, etc for the passed parameter: `arr` unless `arr` is a pointer to an array of pointers (the posted code and the question text do not make this detail clear.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* str = NULL;

for (int i = 0; i < sz ; ++i)
{
    sprintf(str, "%d %d %d\n", arr[i]->server1, arr[i]->server2, arr[i]->weight);
    strcat(buffer, str);
```

When you call `sprintf`, you are asking it to store the results in `str`, but `str` doesn't point to anything.

Also:

```
char* buffer = calloc(50, sizeof(int));
```

Why are you using `sizeof(int)` when the buffer stores text digits, not integers?

You probably want something like:

```
char* serialize(PATH** arr, int sz){

    char* buffer = malloc(sz * 50);
    buffer[0] = 0;

    char str[64];

    for (int i = 0; i < sz ; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(str, "%d %d %d\n", arr[i]->server1, arr[i]->server2, arr[i]->weight);
        strcat(buffer, str);
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be using `snprintf()`, and is there any advantage to the intermediate array, especially when that array is bigger than the allocated buffer?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm just trying to keep things simple.